# mySQL - Unicity constraint depending on other column

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table `item` whose columns are `id` `type` `code` `image`

#### Type column

`type` is a enum and could be `text` or `logo`.

#### Possible situations

If `type === 'text'` then `image` is `null`

If `type === 'logo'` then `code` is `null`

#### What I would like

If `type === 'text'` then the unicity is defined by `code`
If `type === 'logo'` then the unicity is defined by `image`

#### Questions

How can I write this unique constraint in mySQL ? In a migration with laravel ?

Comment: SELECT CASE WHEN x THEN y END

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand your answer

Comment: I have never ever heard about any unicity constraint in mysql. Do you mean unique constraint?

Comment: @Shadow unique yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can declare a unique constraint in that way. You could simplify your table though, by keeping your `type` column but using a single field for the purpose of either `code` or `logo`. You could call this field `value` for example. Then you could add a unique constraint to `type` and `value` like this:

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // Your fields here...

    $table->unique(['type', 'value']);
});
```

For convenience you could always add accessors in your model to access `code` or `image` as if they were fields, for example:

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public function getCodeAttribute()
    {
        return $this->type === 'text' ? $this->value : null;
    }

    public function getImageAttribute()
    {
        return $this->type === 'logo' ? $this->value : null;
    }
}
```

That will allow you to access `code` and `image` as if they were fields and your model will return either the `value` or `null` based on the type of your `Item`.

```
$text = new Item(['type' => 'text', 'value' => 'Hello World!']);
echo $text->code; // Hello World!
echo $text->image; // null

$logo = new Item(['type' => 'logo', 'value' => 'your-image.jpg']);
echo $text->code; // null
echo $text->image; // your-image.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

create code and image column in migration table with default value as null, then if you don't set a value to a column, its value be null automaticaly

```
$table->enum('type', ['image', 'code']);
$table->string('image')->default(null);
$table->string('code')->default(null);
```